# How to create a 3 second timer in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I created a task manager for linux with shell script
I need to refresh the task manager every 3 seconds
I was thinking of using Timer function but got stuck

I have these functions written:

```
getnum
print_form
printinfo
move_user_cursor
```

I got these functions in to a main function such as:

```
init() {
 getnum
 clear
 print_form
 printinfo
 move_user_cursor
}
```

and my script ends like this:

```
init

while true:
 do
  :
done
```

How can I make my script get refreshed every 3 seconds?

```
init(){
  getnum
  clear
  print_form
  printinfo
  move_user_cursor
}

init
while true;
do
  :
done
```

I expect Timer function, or sleep command

Comment: Use the `sleep` command. For example: `sleep 3s`

Comment: You want this to happen asynchronously, without ending the `while true` loop?

Comment: Is `:` a placeholder in your `while` loop, or is it really a loop that does nothing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a timer in Bash Scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1226094/608639), [Run command every second in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9299704/608639), [Repeat a Unix command every x seconds forever](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10646), [Repeat a command every x interval of time in terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/430382), [Repeat command automatically in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13593771/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
init
while true;
do
  :
done
```

with

```
while true;
do
  init
  sleep 3s
done
```

Comment: I don't know why but it doensn't work